# Are there any ways to give a ranger Turn Undead?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead, ranger, paladin, prestige-class

A sequel to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/145160/is-there-any-way-for-a-ranger-to-be-able-to-cast-the-protection-from-evil-spell), where I apparently missed the fact that Prestige Paladin has Turn Undead as a prerequisite. So how about it: are there any ranger variants, ACFs, feats, races, or anything else that can give a ranger Turn Undead? Bonus points for pulling it off by 5th or 6th level.

Comment: I suppose you mean without multiclassing, right?

Comment: This question can be narrowed substantially by referencing [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129422/8610)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No variant ranger or ranger alternative class feature grants a ranger turn undead. (The variant ranger wild defender (*Dragon* #324 95) at level 6 gains the supernatural ability rebuke nature allowing the wild defender to rebuke and command animals and, at higher levels, vermin, plants, fey, oozes, and elementals… but never undead.)

Anyone who meets the feats' easy prerequisites can take the feats **God Touched** and **Divine Channeler** (both *Dragon* #305 42) then 1/day turn undead. This is not an efficient use of feats, but it is, so far as I'm aware, the only feat-based way to turn undead.

(Even the Catalogues of Enlightenment—accessible *via* the feat Planar Touchstone (*Magic of Incarnum* 207)—for all that the planar site can otherwise do still can't grant the ability to turn undead: the granted power of the domain [Sun](http://dndsrd.net/clericDomains.html#sun) (*Player's Handbook* 188), for example, says that it's great turning replaces a normal turn undead attempt.)

Besides using the rules for Items that Grant Feats (*Arms and Equipment Guide* 128) to create an original magic item that grants the feat Divine Channeler—such an item having a price between 15,000 and 20,000 gp according to the guidelines—, I know of no way to have a magic item grant the ability to turn undead.

In the game's vast collection of monsters, there's probably a creature that can, as a racial ability, turn undead. I am, however, unaware of such a creature and I suspect that were such a creature to possess a suitably acceptable level adjustment of +0 or +1 or maybe even in a desperate case +2 that I would've heard of such a creature. Nonetheless, I'm investigating, but I look forward to answers that can confirm or deny the existence of such a creature.

Comment: Even beyond the playable and/or viable LA’s, Metamorphic Transfer, Assume Supernatural Ability, and/or *shapechange* mean one could potentially turn into a creature with turn undead, if one exists. (Then again, manipulate form means a ranger could just, you know, be given turn undead for funsies.)

Comment: @KRyan Chances are, though, if you're using *shapechange* to get turn undead, you're not doing it by 5th or 6th level. *So no bonus points for you!* `:-)`

Comment: @fectin (There must be an easier way—necropolitan and the feat [Momentary Alteration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/27676/8610)?) K makes a good case for the umbrella term claim in his Handbook, and I agree that *turn undead* in a vast majority of cases means *turn or rebuke undead*, but allowing the prestige paladin special requirement *Ability to turn undead* to be satisfied by the brain in a jar's supernatural ability rebuke undead seems way too contrary to what I perceive as the prestige class's intent. I mean, at my table *I* would allow it, but I wouldn't recommend *everyone* allow it!

Comment: The Susurrus, from MMIII, can Rebuke Undead (kinda). However, it is mostly unsuited for being a player character. Also, apparently in previous editions they were plants, which is way cooler than their current status as crystal-y aberrations.